# line 17, in __init__ self.win = tk.Tk() TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, tkinter, typeerror, desktop-application, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to create a desktop interface using tkinter. I have used all the tips on the websites for this problem. It didn't help in any way.
The error is given up by the line: win = tk.Tk(). What should I do to make the code work?  Full code: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1NoUBRFDc76WA1rkUSV5_602drRj9P3f6?usp=sharing

```
win = tk.Tk()
win.title('wave simualator') 
win.geometry('1024x650') 
# win.resizable(False, False)
tabControl = ttk.Notebook(win)  
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)  
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
win.mainloop()
```

Full error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\13\main.py", line 213, in <module>
    win = tk.Tk()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2272, in __init__
    self._loadtk()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2306, in _loadtk
    self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.destroy)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2194, in wm_protocol
    command = self._register(func)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1517, in _register
    f = CallWrapper(subst, func,).__call__
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: There is no `self.win = tk.Tk()` (mentioned in the error) in your posted code.  Only `win = tk.Tk()`.

Comment: Your posted code should not produce the error.  Better post the *full error traceback*.

Comment: @acw1668 I added full error traceback

Comment: Seems like file `__init__.py` of `tkinter` module has been modified.

Comment: When I add in the missing imports, your code works fine for me. It looks like your installation of tkinter might have been corrupted if the exact code in this question actually produces the exact error in the question. Have you tried running your code from a command line outside of pycharm?

Comment: It is from the source code of tkinter: `f = CallWrapper(func, subst, self).__call__`, but in the posted traceback, it is `f = CallWrapper(subst, func,).__call__` which missing the third argument `self`.